# SearchView icon and query text not visible with black background

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, searchview

If I set layout background to black, SearchView widget's icon, text and query text are not visible. I have tried to apply a style, but it's not working. I guess the style was for v7 widget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityGiphy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".presentation.ui.view.GiphyActivity">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/svGiphy"
        style="@style/AppSearchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="input text" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView" >
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:tint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:panelColorForeground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:radius="16dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/white"
        android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

[result with black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VUzZ.png)

How to set the query text, text and icon white?

[result with white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgpkO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using android:theme="@style/AppSearchView", not style="@style/AppSearchView".

```
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/svGiphy"
        android:theme="@style/AppSearchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:queryHint="search for..." />
```

Now the style is correctly applied to SearchView.

[image: searchview]

Answer (score 1):

```
<item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

add it to your style

or just create your custom search view (it will be more flexible)

```
class SearchView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = ViewConst.DEFAULT_STYLE,
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val binding =
        ViewSearchBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)

    var search: String
        get() = binding.searchQuery.hint.toString()
        set(value) {
            binding.searchQuery.hint = value
        }

    fun doAfterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
        binding.searchQuery.addTextChangedListener { afterTextChanged.invoke(it.toString()) }
    }

    fun clear() {
        binding.searchQuery.setText(EMPTY_STRING)
    }
}
```

view_search.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_superlight_gray_corner_10"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/grid_2_5"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/grid_1_75">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/searchQuery"
        style="@style/AppEditText.Search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/grid_0_5"
        android:tint="@color/light_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did not change anything. Even if it would work, it would be only the text, not icons.

Comment: @TalkativeBreakdown I updated my answer, and recommend you solution with custom SearchView